# Validating json with pydantic (fastapi)

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

So I have a request that looks like this

```
[
    {
        "Code": "EVR-T-0dsfdsdf532",
        "Agent": "pacman",
        "Kilometrage": "60000",
        "Operation": "Vidange",
        "Piece_Consomable": "filtre à air",
        "Quantité": 1,
        "UnitPrice": "200.00",
        "Montant": 200,
        "Mainoeuvre": 100
    },
    {
        "Code": "EVR-T-ddsdf53dfds2",
        "Agent": "pacman",
        "Kilometrage": "60000",
        "Operation": "Pneumatique",
        "Piece_Consomable": "(Autre) Uiop",
        "Quantité": 1,
        "UnitPrice": "200.00"
    }
]
```

and my code looks like this

```
@app.post("/utilities/Entretien/submit", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def create_item(item: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    operations = await item.json()
    for i in operations:
        i : EntretienModel
        new_operation = TableEntretien(**i)
        db.add(new_operation)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(new_operation)
    return {"ping": "pong"}
```

I'm basically looping through the array then inserting every object in the database,
I'm looking for a solution that can validate every object with a pydantic model like this one:

```
class EntretienModel(BaseModel):
    Code: str
    Agent: str
    Kilometrage: int
    Operation: str
    Piece_Consomable: str
    Quantité: int
    UnitPrice: float
    Montant: int
    Mainoeuvre: Union[int, None] = None
```

Or another solution better than mine, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a FastAPI operation you can use a Pydantic model directly as a parameter. According to the [FastAPI tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/):

> To declare a **request** body, you use [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) models with all their power and benefits.
>
> [...]
>
> With just that Python type declaration, FastAPI will:
>
> - Read the body of the request as JSON.
> - Convert the corresponding types (if needed).
> - Validate the data
> - [...]

Example:

```python
@app.post("/utilities/Entretien/submit", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def create_item(operations: List[EntretienModel], db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    ...
```